# Objective-C: Why does it matter if you dont release objects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management

If I am messing around with XCode and trying to learn Objective-C, does it pose any threat to my system if I routinely forget to release objects? What is the real consequence of not releasing objects? If I restart my computer will these memory leaks persist?

I am mostly messing with NSStrings and NSTimers and things like that, nothing serious. I'm just concerned about it messing up my computer.

Is there any way to check if there are unreleased objects? What is one to do if they want to check a bunch of code to see if there are any of these memory leaks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only "threat" is that your program will eat up a large chunk of your available memory, which will cause your computer to go slow and your hard drive to thrash until the system reclaims the memory when the program ends. It makes things pretty unpleasant when a program uses more memory than it has to. Not dangerous — just really annoying.

Comment: I think it's important to add that besides being annoying, it just leads to terrible user experience. If your application is associated with horrible memory leaks and overall lag, you can bet no one's going to be especially happy to use it.

Comment: On portable devices like iPhone it's actually dangerous, because it would cause crash when there is not enough memory.  Well, it's actually not crash. The OS will just terminate your process for consuming too much memory.

Comment: @Max: That's a good point, though I still wouldn't describe it as "dangerous" in the sense the OP seemed to be using it. Application crashes are aggravating and I suppose dangerous to your revenue stream, but they generally aren't dangerous to the device running the code. Your iOS device will just kill the app and keep on happily plugging away. I might actually characterize it as less dangerous, because memory exhaustion on a desktop can render the system unusable until you reboot it.

Answer (score 6):

First of all: all processes run in their own virtual memory, so when you kill the process it's memory is being returned to the system no matter how many leaks are there.

Second. By not releasing the object there is no way to tell the system that an object should be freed and that's why all allocated objects will remain in memory even if they are already unnecessary.

Try to start from something like C and not Objective C, cause it's obvious to me that you have no idea what the pointers, RAM and so on really is.

Comment: Answers like those from user Firoze Lafeer are much more welcome than your venomous malice. I actually do know what pointers are, and thanks for the advice but ive already been up to speed with at least beginners C and objective-c. the question is crafted to illicit a specific response from responders. just because you hate your life doesnt mean you need to spread your unhappiness to others (and online at that!)

Comment: @Mooseman hey, what is your problem? if someone doesn't know what happens to the RAM when computer is rebooted, then this is certainly because the low level of knowledges. This is not bad, cause everyone should start from the basics. I've just told you to start from something more simple and didn't want to insult you, while your comment is absolutely offensive.

Comment: @Mooseman Calm down! :) Max wasn't trying to insult you or anything. His last sentence could be phrased better, but what he meant to say was that a deep, solid foundation in C could help one better understand at the machine level and RAM, and for that reason, he believes many beginners would be better off in the long run if they were to start with C, and not something like Objective-C. It wasn't a personal attack or anything like that. In fact, I'd consider your response much worse than his poorly-phrased suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry, any memory you leak will be reclaimed by the OS when your program ends (or crashes).

The leaks and object allocation tools in Instruments will help you find your memory mgmt bugs. Also, the static analyzer (Build->Analyse) is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You won't just take up memory available for your app, you will also take up memory for all other apps on the system. If you take up all the available memory Mac OS X will start moving other applications into virtual memory as well, making the ***entire computer*** slow, not just your app.

On an iOS device, if you use excessive amounts of memory the operating system will kill your app, with no error message to the user, and no chance for you to save any files.

If it's really bad, the app store review team will reject your app from even being submitted to the store. This applies to both the iOS app store and the Mac app store.

You can use the [Instruments app to check for leaks](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/04/02/cocoa-tutorial-fixing-memory-leaks-with-instruments/).

The general rule of thumb, is any time you use a method who's name starts with `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, or `copy` you are responsible for calling `release` or `autorelease` when the object is no-longer needed. And your object's `dealloc` method needs to clear all of it's instance variables.

The newest versions of Mac OS X and iOS support [Automatic Reference Counting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226). I've never used it, but it should make life much easier for new programmers.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't hurt your machine by forgetting to release objects. There's very little that you can do to hurt your machine in software short of deleting system files.

As others have pointed out, all memory used by your program will be reclaimed when the program terminates. If you want to check your program for leaks while it's running, you can monitor it with the Instruments tool that's included with Xcode. I won't try to explain how to use it here -- read the docs and ask if you have trouble.

You can also get some clues that an app is leaking memory by monitoring its memory usage with something like the command line `top` program. If an app's memory usage is constantly increasing as you use it, that's an indication that there may be a leak.